# Why is returning nodes in neo4j faster then returning properties of the nodes?

Tags: neo4j, profiling, cypher

I run similar queries, first returning nodes

```
PROFILE
MATCH (me:USER{userId:"1"})-[:in_group]->(group), (group)<-[:in_group]-(other) 
return group, collect(other) as participants
```

First query execution plan has 105 db hits

[image: First query execution plan]

And second query is different only that it returns properties of the nodes:

```
PROFILE
MATCH (me:USER{userId:"1"})-[:in_group]->(group), (group)<-[:in_group]-(other) 
return group.groupId, collect(other.userId) as participants
```

Ends with longer execution plan with 255 db hits:

[image: Second query execution plan]

Why do we need this projection and eager aggregation to access db if nodes are already fetched? Are they fetched without properties? If so, why don't we have additional db hits in first case, as nodes are returned with their properties.

**UPD:**
I have unique constraint on groupId and userId. The result of `:schema`:

```
Indexes
ON :USER(userId)   ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 
ON :GROUP(groupId) ONLINE (for uniqueness constraint) 

Constraints
ON (user:USER) ASSERT user.userId IS UNIQUE
ON (group:GROUP) ASSERT group.groupId IS UNIQUE
```

Comment: Because in the second query there is a aggregation by the property, which may not be unique and without index. Try to make `group.groupId`  a unique index.

Comment: @stdob-- Looks like it's not the case. I have indexes, updated the question.